# Unable to use discount codes when registering in admin area

Tags: joomla, cividiscount

For an upcoming paid event, we need to register speakers, guests, etc. for free. In attempting to register those people in the admin area, we are unable to use a comp discount code that is for 100% off. Each time we enter the code, it accepts it and changes the total to $0, but upon save we get the error message "Please select at least one option from price set," even though an option was selected prior to submitting.

The discount codes work fine when used on the front-end, but these are courtesy registrations and we want to bypass the confirmation message, since those details have been handled separately.

I was able to work around the issue by creating a new price set for the event that makes use of admin-only options to remove the cost for speakers, however; the issue still remains that the discount codes don't work on the back-end. This has happened on other events in the past, which we by-passed by logging-in as the member and registering via the website front-end. Has anyone else experienced this, and are there troubleshooting steps I can take to find a resolution?

We are running CiviCRM 5.6.0 on Joomla 3.8.13

[image: screenshot of error message]

Updated to add a screenshot of the discount code.
[image: screenshot of discount code]

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, if you use the built-in fees section or a price set with a required price field option (of which you should always have at least one), you will not be able to submit the registration without selecting an option, even if it is a $0 option after applying a discount.

That said, no need to create a separate price set (especially when you are offering only one fee option) - all you need to do is select the $0 option after applying the discount code (or save yourself a click by making the fee option the default), then click the Save button - this will record the registration with a $0 contribution.

If you add a click and remove the "Record payment?" flag that is checkmarked by default when registering someone from the back-office, that will still result in a registration with a status of "Registered" but without the $0 contribution.

Hope this helps,
Tamar

Comment: So there was only one price option in our price set, and we did select it. However, every time we hit submit, it de-selects that option. It simply won't let us select it.

Comment: That sounds odd - can you confirm whether the issue is really with the discount code by attempting to submit a back office registration without using the discount (e.g. register yourself from the back office without entering a discount code) - if you are able to submit without issue, then we can concentrate further troubleshooting on the discount code; if you are unable to submit, then the issue may lie with the price set. Let me know the results!

Comment: Yes back-office registrations work fine without a discount code.

Comment: Hi again - one of our clients just reported an identical issue so now I can get my hands on the full picture - will let you know what I find once I am able to resolve it.

Comment: Hi again - ok, so the issue that was reported actually was unrelated, but if you were able to submit the back office registration without a discount code, then we can assume that the issue lies with the discount code - if you could provide a screenshot of the discount code configuration, that would be helpful in allowing me to attempt to reproduce the issue and perhaps allow me to provide you with an actual response. :-)

Comment: We've had this issue with more than just this particular discount code, but I'll update the original post with a screenshot of the code setup.